# How to go to 'design view ' for a service?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to see the design view of a service in a solution in VS 2010?

Like this?
http://arcanecode.files.wordpress.com/2007/05/windowslivewriterwindowsservicesincaddingtheinstallerpart-14ccfwinservice02-thumb.jpg?w=462&h=249

Comment: You are already looking at it.  It was largely a mistake, a service requires code and you'll have no use for the design view.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm trying to add an installer, that's why I need it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688275/can-i-have-multiple-services-hosted-in-a-single-windows-executable/1688702#1688702

Comment: to elaborate from @HansPassant, Windoze Services have NO Steenkin User Interface.  Therefore, no use for design view.  If you want a user interface, you need to develop a separate application.

Comment: @dar7yl Then, how to add an installer?

Comment: write an other app that installs your service...

Comment: Step-by-step is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169

Comment: @HansPassant "In the Code Editor window, right-click Design View", there isn't Design view when I right click in the Code Editor window.

Comment: Quote: `You are already looking at it`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a complete walkthrough on how to create a service and add installer in VS2010 in this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx).