# Windows Service only runs the first service listed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

My main function is like this:

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
{
    new FirstService(),
new SecondService()
};
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

I want to run two service, but only `FirstService` gets started. Why is that?

Comment: If you comment out FirstService (so that you're only running one service) then does SecondService start?

Comment: possible duplicate so question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688275/can-i-have-multiple-services-hosted-in-a-single-windows-executable

Comment: SecondService's OnStart method does not execute.

Comment: Answer is here, this is right.:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688275/can-i-have-multiple-services-hosted-in-a-single-windows-executable

Answer (score 0):

See this link: http://www.bryancook.net/2008/04/running-multiple-net-services-within.html

Short answer: each service must have own Installer

But I think, that services should be independent and I recomend you to rethink this solution