# Multiple service processes (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase) in one Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, service

I've got two service processes (derived from `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`)
`MyService1` and `MyService2`.

I'm trying to run them both in the `Main()` of a Windows Service's `Programm.cs`.

```
static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = { new MyService1(), new MyService2() };
        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
```

In the `OnStart` methods of both `MyService1` and `MyService2` I write to a log file so I can tell they are running.

The system builds fine and I can install the service.

But only `MyService1` runs. `MyService2` doesn't do a thing (i.e. no start-up log entry). When I change the order in the array:

```
ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = { new MyService2(), new MyService1() }
```

only `MyService2` runs.

To try to get to the bottom of this, I'm using a little tool AndersonImes.ServiceProcess.ServicesLoader (https://windowsservicehelper.codeplex.com/) to get around the limitation that you cannot directly debug a windows service in Visual Studio. With this tool I can get both services `MyService1` and `MyService2` to start and run next to each other. But I still don't know why Windows is running only the first item in the `ServiceBase[] servicesToRun` array.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you do `ServiceBase.Run(new MyService1());` followed by `ServiceBase.Run(new MyService2());`?  Also, do the two have any type of dependency on each other or communication with each other?

Comment: @Dwight No dependency. Currently they don't do anything other than logging to a (their own) file. I tried running both separately. Same result. Only one (the first) of them runs.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688275/can-i-have-multiple-services-hosted-in-a-single-windows-executable

Answer (score 10):

I finally found the answer here: http://www.bryancook.net/2008/04/running-multiple-net-services-within.html. A well hidden resource, thanks 'bryan'! Hopefully this helps the next developer to save time...

The explanation there around ServicesDependedOn isn't quite matching what I see in my project though. It's not about starting them but making sure they are started. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.servicesdependedon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx as well. I don't need this because they do not depend on each other.

Comment: What specific thing that you found there was the fix for you?

Comment: You save my day.

Comment: It is pretty annoying that this behavior is not documented anywhere. I checked my code for several hours and wondered why my second service did not start. Bryan's tip is worth its weight in gold!